# What is the drush command to change a theme in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

What is the drush command to change a theme in Drupal 7?

```
drush theme disable theme_name
drush theme enable theme_name
```

does not work.

Comment: Note that if none of the answers below worked for you, you're probably using a very old version of drush (likely 2.0), which is what you get when installing drush using 'sudo apt-get install drush' on some systems.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Take a look at the comment at http://drupal.org/node/530780#comment-2513534 which has the latest commands related to themes (actually, as of 3.0, but they seem to work with Drush 4.x as well).

- Disable theme: `drush -l http://example.com/ pm-disable theme_name`
- Enable theme: `drush -l http://example.com/ pm-enable theme_name`
- Change theme: `drush -l http://example.com/ vset theme_default theme_name`
- Change admin theme: `drush -l http://example.com/ vset admin_theme theme_name`

Answer (score 23):

You can use:

- **drush vset theme_default THEMENAME**
- **drush vset admin_theme THEMENAME**

For example:

```
drush vset theme_default bluemarine 
drush vset admin_theme shiny
```

These will set the site's default and admin themes, respectively.

Of course, they must both be enabled, preferably beforehand.

Check that things are set up the way you want using:

- **drush status** -- lists the current default and admin themes
- In Drupal 6 - **drush pml | fgrep -e themes** -- to check the status of each theme
  (Enabled, Disabled, etc.)
- In Drupal 7 - **drush pml | fgrep -e Theme**

Comment: if i want to set **admin_theme** with drush in Drupal 8, Then how can we do that ? I mean **vset** is not working with Drupal 8 :(

Answer (score 7):

#### Drupal / Drush 8

The `variables` table has been replaced by the `config` table in Drupal 8, so the drush command `vset` will no longer work. For Drupal8/Drush8 use the following to set the default theme:

```
drush config-set system.theme default THEME_NAME
```

and the following to set the admin theme:

```
drush config-set system.theme admin THEME_NAME
```

Answer (score 6):

```
drush dl theme_name
```

The above command downloads the theme.

```
drush en theme_name
```

The above command enables the theme.
Now, to set the enabled theme as default theme use the below command.

```
drush vset theme_default theme_name
```

Answer (score 4):

this will show you the themes you have:

```
$ drush pm-list --type=theme
```

output:

> Package Name Status Version
>
> Core Bartik (bartik) Enabled 7.25+1-dev
>
> Core Garland (garland) Disabled 7.25+1-dev
>
> Core Seven (seven) Disabled 7.25+1-dev
>
> Core Stark (stark) Disabled 7.25+1-dev
>
> Other ASU WebSpark Bootstrap (openasu_bootstrap) Disabled 7.26-dev
>
> Other Danblog (danblog) Disabled 7.x-1.0
>
> Other Danland (danland) Enabled 7.x-1.0
>
> Other Kalatheme (kalatheme) Disabled 7.x-1.4
>
> Other Kanji (kanji) Disabled 7.x-3.5
>
> Other Responsive Bartik (responsive_bartik) Disabled 7.x-1.0-beta2
>
> Other theme700 (theme700) Enabled 7.x-1.0

and

```
$ drush vset theme_default bartik
```

will change your theme to Bartik.

Answer (score 3):

To know current theme on site move inside project root directory and then

```
drush status theme
```

The above command will tell you the current theme set as default for site and admin both

Now change the site default theme using the below command (use theme name of your choice)

```
drush vset theme_default garland
```

The above command will make garland as default site theme

Now change admin default theme using the below command (use theme name of your choice)

```
drush vset admin_theme garland
```

The above command will make garland as default admin theme

Answer (score 1):

Drush Commands for the specific change

```
drush vset theme_default THEMENAME
drush vset admin_theme THEMENAME
```

For example:

```
drush vset theme_default bird
drush vset admin_theme fly
```

These will set the site's admin theme

Settings for Drush

`drush status` -- lists the current default and admin themes

In Drupal 7 - `drush pml | fgrep -e Theme`